# Ethernet connection lost after starting X server

Tags: networking, archlinux, xorg, firmware

Prior to starting an X server running OpenBox, I am able to `ping` networks successfully. I have tested this by successfully pinging `8.8.8.8` (Google's DNS server).

Soon after launching any graphical application such as a web browser, I am unable to access the Internet. `ping` responds with `connect: network unreachable` when attempting to ping `8.8.8.8`. I can still ping `127.0.0.1` successfully,  but I get the same `network unreachable` error if I attempt to ping my router.

I am using a Model B, overclocked to 800 MHz, running Arch Linux. `pacman -Qi raspberrypi-firmware` shows that version `20130424-1` of the firmware is installed.

The system ran perfectly with both HDMI and composite output and did not drop the connection until recently, when I [enabled HDMI hot plugging](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#No_HDMI_output_at_all) to fix video issues with a new display.

I read the tip on the [ELinux wiki](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Network_connection_fails_when_a_Graphical_User_Interface_is_being_used), but it appears that that issue was fixed last year. Has anyone experienced anything similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this was a power issue. I had previously been using a 1A USB outlet adapter. When I set up my Pi with the new display, I just grabbed whatever adapter was close by, which happened to have only a 0.5A current output.

Now that I'm using the 1A adapter, everything seems fine.

So, if you're getting weird network or other functionality issues that are affected by high CPU usage, check your power source!